# Session variables not working correctly

Tags: php, session, foreach, session-variables

In my code i use a for each and for some reason it takes for ever to load and it screws up half way through with not displaying the name or it just does show up.

Code, http://hastebin.com/axutiqaqev.php (Not displaying correctly here)

```
<?php
$griditems = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
foreach ($griditems->rgInventory as $index=>$items) {
    $_SESSION['itemdesc'] = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
    $_SESSION['itemnamevalue'] = strval($items->classid) . "_" . strval($items->instanceid);
    $_SESSION['itemname'] = $_SESSION['itemdesc']->rgDescriptions->$_SESSION['itemnamevalue']->market_name;
    //echo $index; // will get index
    ?>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
        <a href="#">
            <p><a class="hovertext" href="#" title="<?php echo $_SESSION['itemname']; ?>"><img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/<?= $items->classid ?>/150fx125f" class="thumbnail img-responsive"></a></p>
        </a>
    </div>
<?php
}
session_unset();
?>
```

Website: csgohighroller.com

Everything is working fine but it stops working after i use it once and when a player has too many items.

Example inventory http://www.csgohighroller.com/backpack.php?id=baconcraze

Comment: You clearly have no idea what you are doing. else you wouldn't be repeatedly overwriting the same exact session indexes for no reason. use variables, not sessions.

Comment: @r3wt i was testing out with that because i thought it would work and it didnt make a difference but my main question was on the names of the items disapearing after a couple are shown